# Where should i start in my Riot Api Project?

Tags: api, riot-games-api

I want to create an application using the Riot API that runs whenever I specate a game of League of Legends and creates an interactive streaming overlay using the browser source.

Which things in the Riot API should I read to get all the information out of spectator mode (KDAs of all players, objective timers, team gold, etc.)? And does somebody know if there is a framework in which I can easily create this overlay as a browser source for OBS?

I would like information and maybe some approaches with which I can realize my project.

Answer (score 0):

The project you have planned is only possible locally, so for a game you are either playing or spectating.
There are several solutions to your problem, you could either use the game-client-api which offers not as many features but is overall pretty easy to use:
https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/lol#game-client-api

Otherwise, you could use this community driven project which is using memory reading to extract some more data out of the game. https://github.com/floh22/LeagueBroadcast

The "real" spectator-v4 api by Riot Games unfortunately does not offer any CS or KDA, so it wouldn't really fit into your use case as an overlay.
That's why I would recommend you to visit the unofficial Riot Games Developer Discord Server, if you are capable of, as there are many with knowledge in exactly this topic, if you got any questions left for example.

Comment: Thank u for your answer. I'm going to join the Discord u mentioned.